# Is there any way to revive a dead character

Tags: state-of-decay

In State of Decay I got killed with one of the characters that I have available by a zombie. For me he is my main character and I don't want to play without him. So is there any kind of cheat or modding to revive him or just go back to older saved game before he died without starting from the beginning of the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, sorry.
You will have to start it all over again.
Deaths are permanent in this game.